# как раздвинуть пространство)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, hdd, ssd

проблема следующая
в virtualbox установлена debian, емкость накопителя 20 гб, свободное пространство закончилось
через менеджер виртуальных носителей я увеличил емкость до нужного размера
но внутри система не видит увеличеную емкость, только неразмеченое пространство
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать так что бы dev/sda1 стал на все пространство при этом не потерять данные
нужны идеии возможно я пошел не по тому пути

Comment: Уменьшаешь sda3, раздвигаешь sda2, перемещаешь sda5, ужимаешь sda2, раздвигаешь sda1. Делаешь всё через `gparted livecd`. не забудь про бэкапы.

Comment: На вашем скриншоте всё пространство является размеченным

Answer (score 0):

> как сделать так что бы /dev/sda1 стал на все пространство

1. 

Клонируйте виртуальную машину (смотри в настройках virtualbox), далее испытания проводите с клоном.

2.
Отключаем swap

```
swapoff -a
```

3. 

Удаляем /dev/sda2 и /dev/sda3

```
sfdisk --delete /dev/sda 2 3
```

4. 

Максимально увеличиваем первый раздел **в таблице разделов**

```
echo ",+" | sfdisk /dev/sda -N 1
```

перечитаем таблицу разделов

```
partx --update /dev/sda
```

проверим таблицу разделов

```
sfdisk -V /dev/sda
```

5. 

Изменяем размер **файловой системы**(ФС) до размеров указанных в таблице разделов

проверим ФС до увеличения размера

```
e2fsck -f /dev/sda1
```

увеличиваем размер ФС чтобы она соответствовала указанному размеру в таблице разделов

```
resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

проверим ФС после увеличения размера

```
e2fsck -f /dev/sda1
```

p.s.

на сколько я помню **увеличить** размер файловой системы можно даже на *живом* разделе, хотя надо еще будет затестить, но в любом случае загрузившись через live-систему можно будет проделать вышеописанные действие.